# How to make DIVS hide on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay so, I am trying to make some `<div>`'s dissapear on page load with Javascript, I also have jQuery included.  But here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  hide();
  function hide(){
    floorcontent = document.getElementById('floor_content').hidden = true;
    aboutcontent = document.getElementById('about_content').hidden = true;
    contactcontent = document.getElementById('contact_content').hidden = true;
    homecontent = document.getElementById('home_content').hidden = false;
  }
});
```

Right now it does nothing, but looks right, any ideas?

Comment: Just add style="display:none" to the divs that you want hidden, why do that in JS?

Comment: Your code is completely out of logic..read basics of javascript functions and jquery

Comment: No, it doesn't look right.

Comment: Look guys, I'm new to Javascript.  At least for the most part I'm getting the job done.  I'm only 14, cut me some slack.  Haha

Answer (score 2):

What would be great is if you could give a common class to all the elements you want to hide. For example:

```
<div id="floor_content" class="tohide"></div>
<div id="about_content" class="tohide"></div>
//...
```

Then when you load the page, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tohide').hide();
});
```

That way it would be easier to dynamically add/remove which elements you'd like to hide.

Comment: That wouldn't work with what I'm going for later, unfortunately.

Comment: Another option is `$('div[id$="content"]').hide()` instead of `$('.tohide').hide()`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#floor_content').hide();
  $('#about_content').hide();
$('#contact_content').hide();
$('#home_content').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#floor_content, #about_content, #contact_content, #home_content').hide();  
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    hide_div();
    function hide_div(){
          $('#floor_content, #about_content, #contact_content, #home_content').hide();  
    }
 });
```

add all the `id` or `class` of the `div` you want to hide using comma.

check this : http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/khLv4/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  hide();
  function hide(){
    document.getElementById('floor_content').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('about_content').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('contact_content').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('home_content').style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

This is using plain Javascript to hide. With JQuery you can do;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  hide();
  function hide(){
    $('#floor_content, #about_content, #contact_content, #home_content').hide();
  }
});
```